# after update youtube app not working

Tags: youtube-api

I am using android 4.4.4,after latest update of youtube app,youtube app is not working anymore .after tap on to youtube app  it says error 505,unable to connect to the network. After uninstalling the update youtube works but after update it doesn't work,help me

Answer (score 1):

This may be the problem seeing 505 error ( HTTP version not supported):
Are you behind a firewall or Proxy